# jEuclid: how to show bar in formula with subscript

Tags: math, mathml

In case of mathml:

```xml
<math> 
   <mrow> 
    <mover accent="true"> 
     <mrow> 
      <mi> x </mi> 
      <mo> + </mo> 
      <mi> y </mi> 
      <mo> + </mo> 
      <mi> z </mi> 
     </mrow> 
     <mo>¯</mo> 
    </mover> 
   </mrow> 
</math>
```

jEuclid shows bar over whole formula:
[image]
and it's ok.

But if I add subscript text:

```xml
<math> 
  <msub>
   <mrow> 
    <mover accent="true"> 
     <mrow> 
      <mi> x </mi> 
      <mo> + </mo> 
      <mi> y </mi> 
      <mo> + </mo> 
      <mi> z </mi> 
     </mrow> 
     <mo>¯</mo> 
    </mover> 
   </mrow> 
   <mrow>
   <mtext>v</mtext>
  </mrow>
 </msub>
</math>
```

jEuclid shows bar above `y` and in small font size:
[image]

Is is a jEuclid bug? Is there a workaround solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround solution - first `mrow` should be enclosed in `mstyle`:

```xml
<math>
 <msub>
  <mstyle>
   <mrow>
    <mover accent="true">
     <mrow>
      <mi> x </mi>
      <mo> + </mo>
      <mi> y </mi>
      <mo> + </mo>
      <mi> z </mi>
     </mrow>
     <mo>¯</mo>
    </mover>
   </mrow>
  </mstyle>
  <mrow>
   <mtext>v</mtext>
  </mrow>
 </msub>
</math>
```

The equation displays as expected:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try:

```
<math>
  <msub>
   <mrow> 
    <mover accent="true"> 
     <mrow> 
      <mi> x </mi> 
      <mo> + </mo> 
      <mi> y </mi> 
      <mo> + </mo> 
      <mi> z </mi> 
     </mrow> 
     <mo>&lowbar;</mo>
    </mover> 
   </mrow> 
   <mrow>
   <mtext>v</mtext>
  </mrow>
 </msub>
</math>
```

Comment: it shows similar, only above 'y', not stretchy above whole equation.

Comment: That's a pity. My variant works at least in MathML Central: https://www.mathmlcentral.com/Tools/FromMathML.jsp